# Limits using Epsilon Delta definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\lim_{x \to 3} x^{3}=27 $$

$$ 0<|x-3|<\delta$$

$$|x-3||x^{2}+3x+9|< \varepsilon$$

My teacher said that delta must be in the interval [0,3] but I don't think it's correct.

What is the correct approach to solve this kind of questions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way you would start attempting this problem, after doing what you've already done, is to try to bound $|x^{2} + 3x + 9|$ by some number.  And sometimes you can do that if you assume that $\delta$ is smaller than a number, say, smaller than $1$.  Since, if $\delta < 1$, then $|x - 3| < \delta$ implies $|x - 3| < 1$, so $-1 < x - 3< 1$, so $-1 + 3 < x < 1 + 3$, i.e., $2 < x < 4$.

Then, since $2 < x < 4$, the $2 < x$ gives us that $x$ is positive, while $x < 4$ gives us $|x^{2} + 3x + 9| < |4^{2} + 3(4) + 9|$ (which we can only use if we knew $x$ were positive - why??).  So, we have $|x^{2} + 3x + 9| < |16 + 12 + 9| = 37$.

Then $|x - 3||x^{2} + 3x + 9| \leq 37|x - 3|$.  So, given any $\epsilon > 0$, it should be clear now what we should let $\delta$ equal.  We want $37|x - 3| < \epsilon$ if $|x - 3| < \delta$, so choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{37}$.

But wait!  The above calculations only worked if we assumed $\delta < 1$, so we have to take that into account.  So we should really let $\delta = \min \{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{37} \}$.  If we assume this (so that we are assured $\delta < 1$), then we get by the above work that $|x^{3} - 3^{3}| < 37|x - 3| < 37\frac{\epsilon}{37} = \epsilon$.

Comment: Is it possible  to chose greater than 3 ?

Comment: @Jacksoja I don't understand what you mean.  Do you mean you want to rework this proof where $x \to 4$ or $x \to 5$ or something like that?

Comment: I have problem with the idea that we can chose certain delta on our own , I know that for each delta the problem is different , i.e , computational , but can we chose ANY value of delta in this problem ?

Comment: So basically what I didn't understand were according to my teacher , he said delta must be in the closed interval from [0,3] and cant be something like 4 .

Comment: @Jacksoja Well, think about the definition.  We say for any $\epsilon > 0$, **we can find** a $\delta > 0$ so that $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.  Now, one thing you should think about is this: if we are able to **find** a $\delta$ that works, then we've already found infinitely many $\delta$ that work, because if $\delta$ works, then any $\delta '$ less than $\delta$ also works!  This is because if we know $|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$, then $|x - a| < \delta'$ also implies this since $|x - a| < \delta ' < \delta$.  That's the first point

Comment: @Jacksoja ...I wanted to get across.  The second point is this:  we aren't really choosing any $\delta$.  Given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we are finding a $\delta$ that works.  The argument in my previous comment explains why I am allowed to assume $\delta < 1$.  Because if it works for some $\delta$ larger than $1$, it'll work for every smaller $\delta$, too.  So, we can rightfully assume $\delta < 1$ because of this.  I think when your teacher was saying $\delta$ must be in the interval $[0,3]$, he was probably thinking ahead into the proof and realizing that...

Comment: @Jacksoja ...given the $\epsilon$, any $\delta$ that would work would have to be in $[0,3]$.  I don't know how he got that, so you should ask him, but remember that we are finding a $\delta$ that works for our given $\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay , this cleared many things . Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{27}$. Then, whenever $|x-3| < \delta$, we have: $|x^3 -3^3| = |(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)| < \delta|(x^2+3x+9)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{27} 27 = \varepsilon$ if $|x| \leq 3$.
What if $|x| \geq 3$?

Edit: I forgot to change both $9x's$ that were wrong to $3x$, but it's fixed now.

Comment: your expression of $x^3-3^3$ is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit it quickly

Answer (score 0):

take$ \delta = min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{37})$
then $|x-3||x^{2}+3x+9|< 37|x-3| < \epsilon $